# How to create dynamic ids for tags in django templates

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

Background: I have a dynamic table (as in I don't know its size/elements until runtime) where I am trying to populate a text area with a javascript function. To do this I plan on passing the text area's id along with the values I want to populate it with into the javascript function.

The problem is I am having trouble creating a dynamic id value for each text input field. This is how i am currently attempting to do this:

```
   {% with "input_"|add:applicant.id as idName %}
        <input id="{{ idName }}" type="text" value="">
        <input type="button" hidden="TRUE" onclick="">
        {{ idName }}
        <script>
            putTags({{ idName }}, {{ tags }});
        </script>
   {% endwith %}
```

where the function putTags() will populate the text input's contents. Unfortunately this doesn't work, as it assigns everyone's id to "input_" without appending applicant.id's value (and I have checked, applicant.id has a correct id for each iteration). Am i doing something wrong? Is there an easier way to create these unique IDs?

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this

```
<input id="input_{{ applicant.id }}" type="text" value="">
<input type="button" onclick="putTags('input_{{ applicant.id }}', {{ tags }});">
```

Comment: This was the first way i tried (though I want the value to be populated initially, not when a button is clicked, so I just call function flat out). For some reason it doesn't append the applicant.id correctly. It just makes the id "input_" for all the text boxes.

Comment: Then why do you not just do `<input ... value="{{ tags }}">`? It doesn't sound like something that needs unnecessary javascript...

Comment: I use the function to format the tags. If i just do value="{{ tags }}" it looks something like this: "[<Tag: Apple>, <Tag: Orange>]" where i want it to just say "Apple, Orange"

Comment: You should be able to just do `{{ tags|join:", " }}`

Comment: The view is kind of a mess, but I think I may be able to figure it out on my own. Would it be best to create a field in the applicant object and save the formatted string of tags into that? That way i can just do something like {{ applicant.tagStr }}?

Comment: See my updated previous comment, I forgot about the [`join`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join) filter.

Comment: Wow, you are my hero. Thanks!