# How to set id tag equal to URL name in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mako

I am trying to set dynamic id attribute to the `<body>` tag in the HTML.

Something like this - `<body id="{{ django_view_name }}>"`

I want the `id` attribute to have the page name, like for the homepage `id="home"` and for the blog page `id="blog"` and contact page `id="contact"`

I don't want to use Javascript or Jquery.

I created a `main.html` template and then i am `inheriting` the main template in each of the other templates like `index.html` templates.

The code in `main.html`tag looks like this -

```
<div class="content-wrapper" id="content">
    <%include file="${static.get_template_path('header.html')}" args="online_help_token=online_help_token" />
    ${self.body()}
</div>
```

and then on the `index.html` template i am `inheriting` like this -

```
<%inherit file="main.html" />
```

**UPDATE: REQUIRED ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

How can i evaluate the value of `${ request.resolver_match.url_name }`. For example if `id="${ request.resolver_match.url_name }"` evaluates to `id="home"`, then I want to do something like this -

```
%if ${ request.resolver_match.url_name }=root:
    <div class="container">
else:
    something_else
```

How can i do this? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic ids for tags in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932731/how-to-create-dynamic-ids-for-tags-in-django-templates)

Comment: @AvrilLavigne No, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<body id="{{ request.resolver_match.url_name }}">
```

this will generate id based on your url name you defined in `urls.py` urls

**Update:**
After the edit of question i see that you used mako templates

So you need,

```
<body id="${ request.resolver_match.url_name }">
```

Comment: do i need to import anything specifically for that?

Comment: it added the same thing to the html without computing it. Now, I have `<body id="{{ request.resolver_match.url_name }}" class="ltr  lang_en">` in my page

Comment: how  you calling base template in your view's template ? are you extending layouts ? Can you show bit of your code of templates and views ?

Comment: you are using mako templates with django?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150606/discussion-between-aniket-and-nishant-dixit).

Comment: Then obviously you need to use Mako syntax for the variable, not Django's, surely?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks. Aniket helped me with that. It was a silly mistake.